# Real time javascript calculation based on current text

Tags: javascript, math, addition

I'm very new to javascript, and I'm trying to create a simple real-time calculation.

The idea is that I start with 0 and can use either button to add or subtract, and that the result will be displayed in my 'demo' div.

I'm trying to 'select' that result with var y = document.getElementById("demo").value; but clearly it doesnt work...

I know this might be very inefficient code but I'm still learning

**HTML**

```
<div>Score: <div id="demo">0</div> total points</div>

<button onclick="first()" href="#number-1">this adds 10</button>

<button onclick="second()" href="#number-1">this adds 7</button>

<button onclick="third()" href="#number-2">this subtracts 5</button>

<button onclick="reset()" href="#number-2">reset</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function first() {
    var y = 0;
    var z = 10;
    var x = +y + +z;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

function second() {
    var y = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    var z = 7;
    var x = +y + +z;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

function third() {
    var y = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    var z = -5;
    var x = +y + +z;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

function reset() {
    var y = 0;
    var z = -0;
    var x = +y + +z;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLxoZy

Comment: Div elements don't hold a value `document.getElementById("demo").value` You want to get the `innerHTML` so change all  `var y` to `var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;` and everything will work fine.

Comment: It won't cause problems, but you've gone a bit overboard with the unary plus operator, using it on values that you *know* will already be numbers. (You only *need* it to convert the string values that come from the DOM element, once you fix that part.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because of `document.getElementById("demo").value`, you need to use `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` for collecting value like this -

```
function first() {
  var y = 0;
  var z = 10;
  var x = +y + +z;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

function second() {
  var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var z = 7;
  var x = +y + +z;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

function third() {
  var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var z = -5;
  var x = +y + +z;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

function reset() {
  var y = 0;
  var z = -0;
  var x = +y + +z;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Using `document.getElementById("demo").value`, you can collect form input value & using `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML`, you can collect data from your HTML tag.

Comment: But I have also updated code for making it more easier :)

Comment: A JSfiddle would do. If anything this question should be marked as duplicate and closed. OR at least explain why using `.value` doesn't work and why the OP should use `.innerHTML` then it would make a valid answer.